# Bootstrap, Javascript, process multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I want to submit a form from my site, which uses bootstrap for layout, and as such, the "contact form" is duplicated (1 for large layout, and another for mobile) - but it's the same form, going to the same endpoint.

Since IDs are supposed to be unique - I have to ID the forms differently...

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block" >    
    <form method="POST" action="/signup.php" id="signup-form-A" >
        ...
        <input  name="email"  >
        <button class="btn btn-md" >Sign Up!</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="d-block d-md-none" >    
    <form method="POST" action="/signup.php" id="signup-form-B" >
        ...
        <input  name="email"  >
        <button class="btn btn-xs" >Sign Up!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I really don't want to duplicate my javascript that handles form submission, and I am sure people have figured this out before me coming across this.

What is an efficient "DRY" way of writing a javascript handler to process any number of similar forms on the same page, that, by definition should be ID'd differently.

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: why are you duplicating the form markup for different screen sizes? You should be able to use the same markup for both

Comment: No offense, but if you are using bootstrap and have separate content for mobile and desktop then you're doing it wrong.  Change your markup to work in both places with a single form.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dummy class `signupform` to the forms, then use `$('.signupform')` to get an array containing all forms.